# Phonegap, PHP server login module error

Tags: php, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, login-script

Hi im getting a error when ever i try to run the following jquery script which tries to connect with the PHP server for authentication. Following is my HTML script:

```
<head style="background-color:#C6C6FF;">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="initial-scale=1.0" charset=UTF-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/
libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0rc2/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="login.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="login-box" style="background-color:#C6C6FF;" >
<form>
<table  border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="7">
<tr>
<td  ><div style="font-size:40px; background-color: #C6C6CD;">Login</div></td> 
</tr>
<tr> 
<td><div style="font-size:20px; color:#0000FF">Username</div><div align="left"><input   name="username" id="name" type="text"/></div></td>
</tr>
 <tr>
<td><div>Password</div>
<input name="password" id="password" type="password"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>                                     
<td><input type="submit" id="login" value="Submit" onclick="clickPage()"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
<div id="outp"></div>
<div height="100px">
```

The jquery script for calling the login.php file for authentication.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var serviceURL = "http://localhost/travel/";
console.log("deviceReady");
});

function clickPage(){
alert('hhhhhhh');
console.log("deviceIN");
var name = $('#name').val();
var password = $('#password').val();

 $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: {name: name ,
            password: password},
    url:'http://localhost/travel/login.php',
    success: function(data){

        //$('#outp').text(status);
        alert("Successfully Logged In");
        //$('#outp').text(status);
        nextPage();
    },
    error: function(){
        //console.log(data,status);
        //$('#outp').text(status);
        alert("Failure Loggin In");
    }
}); 

return false;

 };

function nextPage(){
$.extend(  $.mobile , {
     ajaxEnabled: false
   });
  $.mobile.changePage('login.html');
}
```

This is my PHP script

```
//Include database connection details
require_once('connection.php');

//Array to store validation errors
$errmsg_arr = array();

//Validation error flag
$errflag = false;

//Sanitize the POST values
$username = json_decode($_POST['name']);
$password = json_decode($_POST['password']);
$username = 'admin';
$password = 'admin';
//Input Validations
if($username == '') {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Username missing';
    $errflag = true;
}
if($password == '') {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Password missing';
    $errflag = true;
}

//If there are input validations, redirect back to the login form
if($errflag) {
    $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
    session_write_close();
    header("location: index.html");
    exit();
}

//Create query
$qry="SELECT * FROM login WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
$result=mysql_query($qry);

//Check whether the query was successful or not
if($result) {
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        //Login Successful
        session_regenerate_id();
        $member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member['id'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'] = $member['username'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_LAST_NAME'] = $member['password'];
        session_write_close();
        echo "Success What";
        header("location: mainPage.php");
        exit();
    }else {
        //Login failed
        $errmsg_arr[] = 'user name and password not found';
        $errflag = true;
        if($errflag) {
            $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
            session_write_close();
            echo "Failure";
            header("location: index.html");
            exit();
        }
    }
}else {
    die("Query failed");
}
  ?>
```

Everytime I runthis module i get this error "Failure Loggin In" which is an alert when ajax call fails. You can refer the jquery script above for this error. Im not sure where im going wrong .

Comment: does this work in a browser on your computer but not in phonegap?

Comment: no its not working on browser itself.